# Magento 2.4.3: set product image URL from image server

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, configuration

I have a magento 2 website, configuration is as below:

```
- ngnix
- php7.4
- mariadb 10.4
- elasticsearch 7.10
- varnish 7.0
- rabbitmq 3.9
```

**OBJECTIVE - I am looking to use products images from my other image server**

I set my image server URL to magento 2 configuration -

```
stores > configuration > General > Web > Base URL's > Base URL for User Media Files
```

I set my URL and it successfully showing it in each product image.

but the issue is it is adding cache in each URL, due to which products images are not showing.

any thing is wrong in it .

Any help is appreciable, I have done all caching flushing already.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Example - I have a website **[www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)**, and the database already have details regarding images in it. suppose, I have a product p1, so the filename of a image is already saved in mysql database. I have a image server **[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)** and want to access images from this server.

now check product p1 image path if I access it from same server domain then it will be -`www.xyz.com/media/catalog/product/cache/huwovhiendienubfdbnrienow/p/1/p1.jpeg`

because I set media base url, so image is coming like - `www.abc.com/media/catalog/product/cache/huwovhiendienubfdbnrienow/p/1/p1.jpeg`

but I need this coming URL as - `www.abc.com/media/catalog/product/p/1/p1.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

you can disable this by
Admin panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > GENERAL > Web > Url Options > Catalog media URL format

but your webserver should then process the resizing on the go via URL params then.

Comment: check my query again , I updated it